# VS Professional 2017 - 15.9.11 - Issues related to installation

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Two issues faced one during installation and one after the installation.

During installation getting error for one of the package, details below[image]
 Log details: 
 "Something went wrong with the install.

===========================================================================

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.NodeJs,version=1.5' failed to download from 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/6f4871ab-b2c9-44e9-b4fb-

9ca81c7b2f40/63f589ed1fc2af6675dc554745f44005/microsoft.visualstudio.package.nodejs.vsix'.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.NodeJs;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072eff
    Details
        WebClient download failed: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        Bits download failed: File not found.
        WinInet download failed: Function: InternetReadFile, HR: -2147012865, Message: Unknown error 12031
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.8.27906.1)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.8.27906.1)
    Impacted components
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.8.27825.0)
        ASP.NET and web development tools prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.9.28219.51)
        Cloud tools for web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools,version=15.8.27729.1)
        JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.9.28125.51)
        JavaScript diagnostics (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,version=15.8.27729.1)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1)
        TypeScript 3.1 SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.3.1,version=15.0.28218.60)
        Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.8.27924.0)"

**Second Issue:** When I launch web application getting the below error
[image]

Even though I have selected the required workloads as below, getting the error for Install Missing Features

[image]
Tried multiple times uninstall, modify and repair nothing worked. 
Also tried running VS installer in the Admin mode didn't resolved any issues.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/317656/packageidmicrosoftvisualstudiopackagenodejspackage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Download "microsoft.visualstudio.package.nodejs.vsix" from https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/1c1ff821-0a47-4ec3-b1f3-067942471f17/b6ecfdccf3894fac91b8e58caf5e8a9c/microsoft.visualstudio.package.nodejs.vsix
- Create folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.NodeJs,version=1.5"
- Open "microsoft.visualstudio.package.nodejs.vsix" using WinZip and extract "manifest.json" to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.NodeJs,version=1.5" and rename it to "_package.json"
- Copy "microsoft.visualstudio.package.nodejs.vsix" to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.NodeJs,version=1.5" and rename it to "payload"
- Run the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Thanks. These steps helped me to resolve the issue. Few small changes.       
When I got error pop up saying cannot download NodeJs package at that time I clicked on CANCEL button so that installation will be in paused state, then I copied the folder with name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.NodeJs,version=1.5"  which will have two files (_package.json and payload.vsix) . Then click on RETRY button on VS installer and installation was successful.  Also before doing these steps uninstall VS2017 first and then try fresh installation.